# FFMpeg-PHP Installation Error

Tags: php, ffmpeg, centos

While installing FFmpeg-PHP, I got this interesting error:

```
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAudioStreamId':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1051:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAudioChannels':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1089:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAudioSampleRate':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1125:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAudioBitRate':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1161:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'zim_ffmpeg_movie_getVideoBitRate':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1181:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function '_php_read_av_frame':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1204:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1215:
warning: implicit declaration of
function 'avcodec_decode_video'
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1219:
error: 'PKT_FLAG_KEY' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function '_php_get_av_frame':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1246:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared
(first use in this function)
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1282:
error: 'AVCodecContext' has no member
named 'hurry_up'
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1284:
error: 'AVCodecContext' has no member
named 'hurry_up'
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:
In function
'_php_get_sample_aspect_ratio':
/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1443:
error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared
(first use in this function) make: ***
[ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1
```

When I ran `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep ffmpeg`, I got this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library
'/usr/lib/php/modules/ffmpeg.so' -
libavformat.so.52: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory
in Unknown on line 0
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I am running on Centos.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using YUM? Also, ServerFault.com might be a better place to ask this, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

for this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
load dynamic library
'/usr/lib/php/modules/ffmpeg.so' -
libavformat.so.52: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory
in Unknown on line 0
```

With your ffmpeg configure options you will need

```
--enable-shared
```

If you are still having issues check the paths:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
 echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/custom-libs.conf
 ldconfig
```

Run:

```
ldconfig
```

After

```
make && make install
```

Comment: What type of OS/Distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the libavformat library. You should be able to install this via the yum package manager.

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

If it still doesn't work, try installing the development library

```
yum install ffmpeg-devel
```

Comment: @sreimer I already have ffmpeg installed. When I ran ffmpeg I got this information (I didn't post it all):

"FFmpeg version git-N-29309-gc225615" //
"libavcodec   53.  1. 0 / 53.  1. 0"

I also tried installing the development library but that didn't work either. The same error appears each time I try to install FFmpeg-php

Comment: According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/issues/detail?id=24) not having libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev and libswscale-dev installed will produce a similar error.

Comment: @sreimer All of those are installed. Could it possibly be the version of ffmpeg?

Comment: are you compiling from source?

Comment: @sreimer I used `git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git`. Is there a better way?

Comment: try using CentOS's package manager `yum` - that way you get something that's been tested and all the dependencies are retrieved automatically

Comment: @sreimer Will that install the latest version? Would I have to remove the current ffmpeg before I run `yum install ffmpeg` ? Thanks!

Comment: It may not be the newest but it should be close. You'll have to install to find out. And you should remove the current one first

Comment: @sreimer I now get this error: `/usr/downloads/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1443: error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1`

Comment: So you're back to the same error. I would try the [ffmpeg-php group](http://groups.google.com/group/ffmpeg-php?pli=1) for help

Answer (score 0):

Check your system for libavcodec/libavformat, it may just be missing from your library path, or you may have a different version than expected installed.

```
find / -name 'libavformat*.so*' -print
```

and see what it comes back with, if you have libavformat.so.53 when your installed ffmpeg is expected .so.52, there is your problem.

Comment: If so, just create a symlink, for e.g: `ln -s /usr/lib/libavformat.so.53 /usr/lib/libavformat.so.52`.

Comment: That is not a great idea, it would be better to recompile ffmpeg to link to the proper libraries, although as long as you are going backwards, not forwards, it might work.

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘avcodec_init’