# Best method to install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php?

Tags: php, centos, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FFMpeg-PHP Installation Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/263297/ffmpeg-php-installation-error)

I'm able to get FFmpeg installed on my server but ffmpeg-php NEVER installs correctly. This happens every time:

[FFMpeg-PHP Installation Error](https://serverfault.com/questions/263297/ffmpeg-php-installation-error)

Is there something wrong with the ffmpeg installation?

**How should I install ffmpeg on CentOS 5.5 32-bit? What method is preferred knowing that ffmpeg-php needs to be installed later?**

This has been bothering me for weeks and I need to find a solution soon.

Thanks!

Comment: @ErikA I just linked to that... This is a different question. I'm asking for advisable methods of installing ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php (not on how to fix that error).

Comment: This is essentially the same question. The other question suggested you try and install using `yum`. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Install using RPM
2. Compile from source

For installing RPM, you can enable any third-party repo like DAG and then simply do

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

To enable DAG repo, simply install the RPM,

```
rpm -ivh http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Note: you still need to install ffmpeg-php from source or you may need to update php from the DAG repo itself (which I don't advise).

For compiling from source, you need to download each and every ffmpeg & related modules which you want to install and then compile it. Or, you can simple use any autoinstaller scripts available in the net to compile ffmpeg for you.

eg: http://scriptmantra.info/2008/06/yum-ffmpeg-svn-client-installation-script/